# Issue with pip instalation of pyqt5

Tags: python, pip, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to install pyqt5 using pip. I did it, but in code it still doesn't recognise pyqt5.

```
pip install pyqt5
Requirement already satisfied: pyqt5 in /home/pawl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (5.15.6)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.8 in /home/pawl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5) (12.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: PyQt5-Qt5>=5.15.2 in /home/pawl/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyqt5) (5.15.2)
```

It is the ouput of terminal. But the error still exist:Import Pyqt5 cannot be resolved.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to paste the *exact* import line you're using.

Comment: Probably a typo. Try: `from PyQt5 import QtCore`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a typo
make sure to write

```
from PyQt import QtCore
```

Also check for PyQt5 in Python path.